# Launching a pdf asset from android menu?

Tags: android, launch

I have included a file called "Manual.pdf" in my assets folder.  I have created a menu button called "Help".  I want the user to be able to go to the menu, press on the Help button, and launch the Manual.pdf file in whatever viewer the phone has installed.

I have read for a few hours on this site and other sites, but I just can't get the file to launch.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unified PDF reader for Android Devices. I assume that in the course of your research you would have found that, you could use an implicit intent to invoke a pdf reader if it does exists.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.setType("application/pdf");
```

It works in some devices and fails in some other devices. ( so please check availability of intent using the package manager). If you are targeting a particular device then you could get the corresponding Activity Object and use an Implicit Intent.(com.htc.pdfreader for HTC Phones).

Comment: When I use Intent to open a website, a window pops up that makes me chose which browser I want to use.  When trying to open a pdf in a file explorer, a window will pop up and ask me to decide which pdf viewer I want to use. How do I do the same with a pdf file stored in assets?

Comment: The difference is opening any intent of browsable activity is inbuild in all android devices. That is not the case with pdf. For some reason android did not support a native pdf reader yet.